# The type org.hibernate.bytecode.javassist.FieldHandled cannot be resolved with hibernate version 5.4.18.Final

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to migrate the versions of spring framework as well as that of hibernate. For spring framework I moved the version from 3.2.18 to 4.3.20. After that I have upgraded hibernate version from 3.5.6-Final to 5.4.18.Final. I did all the migration related changes to make my code compilation free. But eventually I got a blocker for building the project. At the build time I got some error message like " The type org.hibernate.bytecode.javassist.FieldHandled cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files".

Can anybody please help me to sort out this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This class is no longer present in Hibernate 5. Most likely you still have some old dependencies on your class path, either parts of Hibernate 3 or something compiled against Hibernate 3. What dependency management tool do you use?

Comment: @Sergei Thank you for the comment. Yes, I know this class is no longer present from hibernate version 5.1 onwards. I am using maven in my project as dependency management tool. Actually I did a static scan in veracode and veracode was recommended me to use hibernate 5.4.18 version or newer versions. So, as per veracode 5.4.18 is the minimal version that I can incorporate in my code. I have removed all of my older hibernate3 components from my pom.xml and no older hibernate dependency is present in my dependency hierarchy section. Please advise me to sort out this issue.

Comment: To make sure no older dependencies are present, you can run `mvn dependency:tree` to output the tree of dependencies for the project, and search for unexpected hibernate versions in the output.

Comment: Only two hibernate components present in my dependency tree(i.e., hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final and hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final). Is any particular annotation present in entity class responsible for this issue. Actually I don't know how Field Handled is used and what is the main task of this class. @Sergei Could you please explain.